# Retorno antecipado de um fold

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin permite [retornos para etiquetas previamente declaradas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels), incluindo etiquetas implícitas.

Exemplo da documentação:

```
fun foo() {
  ints.forEach {
    if (it == 0) return@forEach
    print(it)
  }
}
```

Nesse espírito, eu gostaria de fazer uma expressão lambda retornar antecipadamente um `fold`. 
Isto é:

```
val array = intArrayOf(3, 2, 1, 4)
val firstEvenSum = array.fold(0, {acc, n -> 
    val sum = acc + n
    if (sum % 2 == 0)
      return@fold sum
    sum                              
})
println("First even sum is: $firstEvenSum")
```

Nesse caso eu gostaria de obter `6` (retorno antecipado da função `fold` em `3 + 2 + 1`). Porém, parece que o `return@fold` está simplesmente retornando da expressão lambda e continuando com o `fold` normalmente (resultado `10 = 3 + 2 + 1 + 4`).

Existe alguma maneira de fazer esse retorno antecipado?

Comment: Este recurso da linguagem parece bem legal, ainda não sei quase nada mas gosto de Kotlin. Isto seria algo como o `yield`? Expressão lambida :D

Comment: Também estou tentando explorar. Gostei bastante (um bom meio termo entre Scala e Java). Parece que eles tem planos para suportar `yield` oficialmente no futuro. Isso está mais para  *labels on steroids* :).

Comment: @bigown, so vi a expressão "lambida" agora hehehe. Valeu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O melhor *workaround* que encontrei foi embrulhar o `fold` com uma [*IIFE*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (estilo JavaScript). Dessa forma posso usar `return sum` sem nenhum *label*.

```
val firstEvenSum = fun(): Int {
    array.fold(0, {acc, n -> 
        val sum = acc + n
        if (sum % 2 == 0)
            // retorna da funcao anonima, nao da expressao lambda
            return sum
        sum  
    })
    throw NoSuchElementException("No partial even sums") 
}();
```

Por outro lado teoricamente eu não estou retornando do fold e sim da função anônima que embrulha o fold. Deve ter um jeito menos feio de fazer isso.